# Tell ProGuard to obfuscate a given method, but to don't change its name

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I have a method like this:

```
public static void aBeautifulMethod(String userId) 
{
    int aNumber = 0;
    String something = userId;
    // ....
}
```

Is it possible to tell Proguard to obfuscate it as usual, but preserving its name? The result should be like this:

```
public static void aBeautifulMethod(String a) // name doesn't change!
{
    int b = 0;
    String c = a;
    // .... everything is obfuscate inside
}
```

Note that I'm looking for a way to apply this rule to **a precise set of methods**. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -keep options apply to the entry points, not to the code, so it does what you describe:

```
-keep somepackage.SomeClass {
    public static void aBeautifulMethod(java.lang.String);
}
```

You can use -keepclassmembers if the class name may be obfuscated.

You can specify more methods and use various wildcards, as explained in the ProGuard manual.

Comment: Thank you, actually I've already solved it by doing a similar thing: "-keepclassmembernames" and Annotations on the code.